# trying to make asp net registration form on live server. What should be the correct way?

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP .NET registration form which is working on the local server. How can I put it on the live server? Do I just need to change the connection string?

Comment: There isn't nearly enough information, the question is too vague and I don't think anyone can help you unless you provide some more details/code and you are more specific. Good questions yield good answers